# Why is my background spread across the browser when I set body {width: 960px; margin: auto 0;}?

Tags: html, css

So I have this very basic question that I was wondering about. I just set a background through css with

```
body {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url("../img/background2.jpg");
}
```

Why is the image showing up at both sides as well and not only in the center 960 pixels? If I put my background image in a navigation class selector, it does work:

```
.container {
background: #099;
}
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the body image be restricted by the width that I set?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nB22j/

Also, is there any use for the .container selector if I can just put everything in body {} ? (In this case I do want the background to fill the full browser so I can put my background in body {} but I'm just wondering...) I'm not sure anymore why I added the container div in the first place. Any reason for it to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, if you set no background to HTML , body's background is applied to HTML too.

Just add this : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nB22j/1/)**

```
html {
background:#fff;/* or any color/image/gradient you want */
}
```

and your background for body will only be drawn where body stands.

See **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html)** for more infos.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. :) Thanks!